# Pulling an image online and rendering it through a Django template

Tags: django, image

I am trying to pull an image online and have it appear on my site, but I am having trouble with getting it into the Django template html file.

## views.py

```
def testing(request):
picture_page = "http://geology.com/world/world-map.gif"
opener1 = urllib2.build_opener()
page1 = opener1.open(picture_page)
my_picture = page1.read()
filename = "my_image" + picture_page[-4:]
fout = open(filename, "wb")
fout.write(my_picture)
fout.close()
myfile = urllib2.urlopen("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/catalogs/eqs1day-M1.txt")
return render_to_response("ind.html", {'myfile':myfile, 'fout': fout}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## html file

```
{{fout}}<img src="my_image.gif"/>
```

The fout part renders this:
While the img tag renders a "Didn't find image" picture. Is this because the created "my_image.gif" is made in my project directory and not the media folder that usually holds images for Django?

Comment: From my code, can you tell me how to save the image to a different directory on my computer, as opposed to the cwd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of all that what don't you just put the image url into the template i.e

`<img src="http://geology.com/world/world-map.gif" />`

That should be able to work fine

Comment: I figured out the problem, but stack overflow wont let me mark this answered cause I'm new or something. Thats basically what I did bu using the STATic_URL defined in my settings.py to map the image to the right media directory, so like src="{{STATIC_URL}}/picname.jpg"

Comment: I think he also wanted to save the image locally before displaying it.